# Setting the value of the "action" attribute of a form to the index page

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion

I've noticed something whilst working on the login form I have been creating and was wondering if anybody else had spotted this problem/issue before. When creating a form and entering the value for the action attribute, it works fine for every page except for the index.cfm page. Below is some example code to give you an understanding of my problem.

```
<form action="index.cfm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username"></input>
    <input type="password" name="password"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
</form>

<cfif IsDefined("form.username")>
    <p>Welcome!</p>
<cfelse>
    <p>You have not been logged in.</p>
</cfif>
```

The above example, doesn't work, however, the example below, does;

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username"></input>
    <input type="password" name="password"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
</form>

<cfif IsDefined("form.username")>
    <p>Welcome!</p>
<cfelse>
    <p>You have not been logged in.</p>
</cfif>
```

This problem is on the index page ONLY. On all other pages, entering the file name and any URL variables required works with no issues at all. Could anybody provide a hint or reason as to why this is happening or where I might be going wrong?

EDIT:
I have included code to give a clearer idea of my situation. In the first example, the output would be "You have not been logged in" when I enter any given text into the username field and submit the form. Whereas, the second example, i receive the alternative value of "Welcome!" upon submitting the form. Hope this clears up my problem.

Comment: The term, "doesn't work" is too vague.  What does it actually do?

Comment: It doesn't work. Nothing is submitted. The idea of a form is to submit, therefore, if it doesn't work, it doesn't work.

Comment: This still does not help us to reconstruct your problem. Please at least give the URL to a live example, if your own debugging skills are not existent.

Comment: If a form doesn't submit this implies a client-side problem, at least until you give more details of what is actually happening.  Check your JS.

Comment: @CBroe I'm currently studying how to program, I've been doing it for 3 months. I'm no expert. All i'm asking is if anyone has encountered the problem with submitting forms on the default page for a directory. And I don't have a live URL as the site is not live yet.

Comment: Can you post your CF version and what version of IIS you are using?

Comment: ColdFusion 10 and IIS7. These are not the problems though.

Comment: Does the index.cfm page contain the `<cfif IsDefined("form.username")>` lines?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes because I'm including the file into the index.cfm page, but no because it is on the page that I am including to the index.cfm page.

Comment: @LeeB can you post ALL of your code? Every piece affected by this needs to be posted.

Comment: @MattBusche No i can't there is physically too much to post. However, I apologise for snapping. I just tested `<form action="index.cfm" method="post">` along with the following code which I provided in my post and it has submitted perfectly fine. The one thing I have noticed however, when I did submit the form, /index.cfm was appended onto the URL string, however when I do it on the site i am working on, that isn't appended onto the URL string.

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem, after testing it on the external site, i realised the issue traced back to the URL re-write rules. To solve the problem i needed to use the directory name as the action value rather than the actual page itself, as the index.cfm document is the default document for the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out URL re-write was removing `index.cfm` when I used the URL's below (because it is the default document):

- `<form action="/index.cfm" method="post">`
- `<form action="index.cfm" method="post">`

Therefore, I needed to use the directory name as the action. In my case this code solved my issue:

```
    <form action="/community/" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious issue is you haven't given your input a name. There's nothing being submitted without a name, but the form does submit, it just doesn't contain any data.

```
<form action="index.cfm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="afield"></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: For the above example, I missed it out - which I will edit now. However, I can assure you that I have both of my fields named in my form. The reason i NEED the action field is that I'm using the page as an include to be used on multiple pages, so the action is equal to the cgi script name rather than a static location. This allows the users to login from more than one page using the same include.

Comment: @LeeB why would you not post the EXACT code you're having issues with? Creating new code with new bugs isn't going to help.

Comment: Because currently that is the EXACT code. Read my edit and you might understand a little clearer what my problem is.

Comment: @LeeB you just said `For the above example, I missed it out`, so it wasn't the exact code. Have you tried posting to a different url, i.e. `index2.cfm` ?

Comment: I meant by mistake, not purposefully. And yes, I explained in my post I have tried with several other pages and I have no issues. I already have several forms across my site that have worked no problem, this just happens to be the first I need to submit on an index page and I have encountered this issue.

Comment: I didn't ask for your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: @LeeB it isn't an opinion, it is an observation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I've flagged your comment up as it isn't productive.

Comment: @LeeB If it helps you learn to ask productive questions, the comment IS productive.  If it doesn't help you then, that's your deal.

Comment: You just decided to have a pop at me for no reason. I don't post questions for the sake of posting them, I do it to help me and others. There is nothing wrong with replicating an example. I don't exactly want to copy + paste all of my code onto a site for everyone to see.

Comment: @LeeB I didn't take a pop at you. I simply stated that you make it difficult for us to help you with your questions worded the way they are and irrelevant examples. Your questions get voted down for a reason, and soon people aren't even going to try ciphering  your questions to find what you're really after. I may lack tact but I'm trying to help you ask better questions. Down voting and asking for more info over and over doesn't seem to help. A good question would have a valid example or exact code, what you've tried, errors or descriptions of bad behavior (not "doesn't work").

Comment: @Travis as i stated, a form is designed to send or receive information, if it "doesn't work" it means that whichever method you are using "doesn't work" because something is hindering it. My point was that something to do with the index.cfm page was causing the action method to not work, therefore it is hardly vague to state that. In fact, if you DID look at my other questions, you will see i put more effort into making this one less vague for people to pick apart and help me with my problem.